# Prevent deletion of parent row if it's child will be orphaned in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, relationship

I'm currently building a data model using sqlalchemy through flask-sqlalchemy

The database is on a Postgresql server

I am having trouble when deleting rows from a table that has relationships. In this case I have a number of treatment types, and one treatment. the treatment has a single treatment type assigned.

As long as I have one or more treatments assigned a particular treatment Type, I wish that the treatment type cannot be deleted. As it is now it is deleted when I try.

I have the following model:

```
class treatment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'treatment'
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('title', 'tenant_uuid'),)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    tenant_uuid = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    treatmentType_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('treatmentType.id'))
    riskResponse_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('riskResponse.id'))

class treatmentType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'treatmentType'
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('title', 'tenant_uuid'),)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    tenant_uuid = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    treatments = db.relationship('treatment', backref='treatmentType', lazy='dynamic')
```

I can build some logic in my "delete" view that checks for assigned treatments, before deleting the treatment type, but in my opinion this should be a standard feature of a relational database. So in other words I must be doing something wrong.

I delete the treatment type like so:

```
entry = treatmentType.query.filter_by(tenant_uuid=session['tenant_uuid']).all()
    try:
        db.session.delete(entry)
        db.session.commit()
        return {'success': 'Treatment Type deleted'}
    except Exception as E:
        return {'error': unicode(E)}
```

As I said it is possible for me to do a check before deleting the treatment Type, but I would rather have sqlalchemy throw an error if there are relationship issues prior to deletion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When deleting the `TreatmentType` (parent), [by default](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#delete), SQLAlchemy will update the child by setting the `Treatment.treatmentType_id = None`. As you stated, you are left with a `Treatment` without a `TreatmentType`. The child record is now an "orphan".

There are 2 ways to prevent orphaned records from being created in SQLAlchemy.

**1. Using a Non-NULL constraint on the child column**

When deleting the `TreatmentType` (parent), by default, SQLAlchemy will set the `Treatment.treatmentType_id` (child) to `None` (or null in SQL) when you perform this operation, and as you stated, you are left with a `Treatment` without a `TreatmentType`.

A solution to this is to update the `treatmentType_id` column to be **non-nullable**, meaning that it MUST have a non-null value. We use the `nullable=False` keyword to do this:

```
treatmentType_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('treatmentType.id'), nullable=False)
```

Now, when the default cascade logic executes, SQLAlchemy tries to set `Treatment.treatmentType_id = None`, and an [IntegrityError](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError) is raised due to the non-null constraint being violated.

**2. Using passive_deletes='all'**

```
treatments = db.relationship('treatment', backref='treatmentType', passive_deletes='all')
```

When a `TreatmentType` gets delete, the `passive_deletes='all'` keyword on the `treatments` relationship "[*will disable the “nulling out” of the child foreign keys*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html?highlight=passive_deletes#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.passive_deletes)". It basically disables the default behavior outlined in the first paragraph above. So, when the ORM tries to delete the `TreatmentType` **without** first setting the child's `Treatment.treatmentType_id = None`, the database will throw an [IntegrityError](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError) complaining that the child's ForeignKey references a non-existent parent!

**Note: The underlying database MUST support foreign keys to use this option*

Comment: Thank you Aelfinn

This is the way to go in this instance. And in many more similar I have currently.

But what to do when the related item is optional?

Comment: The answer has been updated with the `passive_deletes='all'' keyword - this should get you what you're looking for.